# Combining awk commands

Tags: awk

I currently have this piece of code:

```
read -p 'Enter the fruit you want to search: ' user_fruit
awk -F ":" -v re="$user_fruit" '$4 ~ re' $fruit_file
```

Which uses awk to find matches in `$4` that match with the pattern provided by the user under the `$user_fruit` variable in the `$fruit_file`. However, I need to alter the awk command so that it only displays line matches when the word `apple` is also on the line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the awk pattern using boolean operators:

```
read -p 'Enter the fruit you want to search: ' user_fruit
awk -F ":" -v re="$user_fruit" '/apple/ && $4 ~ re' "$fruit_file"
```

I.e. print records when the record matches `/apple/` *and* the fourth field matches the regex.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to check for the presence of *literal*, *fixed* strings, you can ise `index` instead of the regex search:

```sh
read -p 'Enter the fruit you want to search: ' user_fruit
awk -F ":" -v re="$user_fruit" 'index($0, "apple") && index($4, re)' file
```

Here,

- `index($0, "apple")` - checks if there is `apple` substring on the whole line (if its index is not `0`)
- `&&` - `AND` condition
- `index($4, re)`  - checks if there is `apple` substring in Field 4 (if its index is not `0`).

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/BYernE):

```sh
s='one:two:three:2-plum+pear
apple:two:three:1-plum+pear'
user_fruit='plum+pear'
awk -F ":" -v re="$user_fruit" 'index($0, "apple") && index($4, re)' <<< "$s"
#index($3, "snow") != 0
# => apple:two:three:1-plum+pear
```

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for the valuable input, and sorry about the forgotten link :)